# Crawl a webpage which is generated by Javascript

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl the data from [this website](https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E4%B8%8E)

I only need the text *"Pictograph - A spoon 勺 with something 一 in it"*

I checked **Network -> Doc** and I think the information is hidden here.

[image]

Because I found there's a line is 

`i.length > 0 && (r += '<span>&raquo;&nbsp;Formation:&nbsp;&nbsp;<\/span>' + i + _Eb)`

And I think this page generates part of the page that we can see from the [link](https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E4%B8%8E).

However, I don't know what is the code? It has html, but it also contains so many `function()`.

---

**Update**

If the code is `Javascript`, I would like to know how can I crawl the website not using `Selenium`?

Thanks!

Comment: page uses `JavaScript` to add this element so you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run `JavaScript`

Comment: @furas But I think Selenium it's not very efficient, so I'm wondering if there's any other ways to crawl the website?

Comment: if you find JavaCode which adds it then you can try to write the same in Python. If JavaScript loads data from some URL and you can find it then you can use it download it without Selenium. Maybe Selenium is slower but it is faster to create solution. I already have code for this with Selenium.

Comment: check [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) - it is old but some information can be still useful. Many of them are based on WebKit engine which is/was used in web browsers.

Comment: BTW: I got this cached file with line which you found but it is very long and obfuscated so it is impossible to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This page use `JavaScript` to add this element. Using `Selenium` I can get HTML after adding this element and then I can search text in HTML. This HTML has strange construction - all text is in tag so this part has no special tag to find it. But it is last text in this tag and it starts with `"Formation:"` so I use `BeautifulSoup` to ge all text with all subtags using `get_text()` and then I can use `split('Formation:')` to get text after this element.

```
import selenium.webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E4%B8%8E')

soup = BS(driver.page_source)
text = soup.find('div', {'id': "charDef"}).get_text()
text = text.split('Formation:')[-1]

print(text.strip())
```

---

Maybe `Selenium` works slower but it was faster to create solution.

If I could find url used by `JavaScript` to load data then I would use it without `Selenium` but I didn't see these information in `XHR` responses. There was few responses compressed (probably `gzip`) or encoded and maybe there was this text but I didn't try to uncompress/decode it.